# Getting error in executequery in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hibernate-mapping

I have written a hql query in grails inside controller and while executing it i am getting error such as

> unexpected token: where near line 1, column 166 [FROM com.ashwin.Training tr where tr.id NOT IN (SELECT t.training_id from com.ashwin.User u INNER JOIN com.ashwin.TrainUser t on u.id=t.user_id where u.id=t.user_id where u.id=:uid)]".

MY Hibernate query is

```
def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser.id
def trainingList=Training.executeQuery("FROM Training tr where tr.id NOT IN (SELECT t.training_id from User u INNER JOIN TrainUser t on u.id=t.user_id where u.id=t.user_id where u.id=:uid)",[uid:currentUser])
             [trainingLists:trainingList]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In inner select you have this

```
t on u.id=t.user_id where u.id=t.user_id where u.id=:uid
```

Double where is incorrect. And also you already define join rule. So the correct statement is

```
FROM Training tr where tr.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT t.training_id from User u INNER JOIN TrainUser t 
    on u.id=t.user_id where u.id=:uid)
```

Comment: i changed where to AND i error such as "could not locate named parameter [uid]"

Comment: Show your code. And why do you changed WHERE to AND? This statement after JOIN ON is useless